# Active high-active low for preset

Tags: digital-logic, flipflop, ripple-counter

In a FF when clear is 0, output is also 0.So what should it be considered as ? Active low or high clear? If it active low doesn't it mean that output should be 1 ?

Comment: "Active LOW" just means that it is active when low. It doesn't necessarily say anything about dependent outputs. Their value will be specified in the datasheet. But you cannot assume anything as necessarily true without the datasheet as your guide. So can you show us the datasheet for the FF you are discussing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

**Preset** and **Clear** are two asynchronous inputs in a Flip-Flop.

"Preset" is used to set its output to '1' and "Clear" is used to reset its output to '0'.

Active-low Preset means the Flip-Flop output is set to '1' when the Preset = '0'

Active-low Clear means the Flip-Flop output is reset to '0' when the Clear = '0'

Similarly,

Active-high Preset means the Flip-Flop output is set to '1' when the Preset = '1'

Active-high Clear means the Flip-Flop output is reset to '0' when the Clear = '1'